# Android Device chooser not recognizing my Nexus 7

Tags: android, nexus-7

I am using my Mac for android development and have used my Nexus 7 for almost a year now as my go-to device for testing my apps. Recently my device started getting unrecognized by computers even in windows as well in my Mac. For Eclipse's Android Device Chooser my device will show for about 0.01 sec then suddenly disappear. My Android File Transfer app no longer functions because it can't see my device.

I did my research and none of the answers gave me any relief. I've tried the adb kill-server/adb start-server, restart Mac, restart device restart eclipse. My usb debugging is turned on and still my device can't be recognized. It's not also in adb devices list. The irritating thing is it will show for 0.01 sec in device chooser then disappear. Is there a solution here? Maybe an update of the device?

I tried different phones and they were all recognized.

Comment: Did you try it with a different usb cable? Maybe something is wrong in the phisical layer, with the cable or the phone's microUSB port... Do you see it in the file System?

Comment: I've only tried it with one other cable and it problem still remains..how would I know if there is a problem with the microUSB port?

Comment: Well, if not just Eclipse see your phone for a short time, but also your computer than the problem is not with your adb or debug connecton. It should be a driver or a hardware problem.

Comment: Maybe it is a hardware problem. I connected my Nexus to a laptop with Windows OS and it says the device has some malfunction or something. What hardware problem could make this happen? Or is it because of a virus that it can't be detected?

Comment: I don't think it's a virus, and windows says that pretty often, even when there is no problem, so don't be so sure XD. Any connection problem can be, abrasion of the microUSB port of your phone for example can cause a problem like that I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the problem was but when I upgraded my Nexus 7 to Lollipop 5.1 it suddenly got recognized. Android File Transfer was opening flawlessly as well as being listed in adb devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had two things: either no IDE device popping up or a device popping up in device manager with an unrecognized driver. Plugged USB cable into back of computer instead of front USB array and everything started to work. Must be my front USB faceplate dying :(